# How to pass cyrillic symbols in CMIS query?

Tags: api, alfresco, cmis, cyrillic, ansi-sql-92

I'm using CMIS query language to query information from my Alfresco server. Some of content's properties have Cyrillic names. When I try to insert this names in `WHERE` clause, I get an error:

```
[exception] => invalidArgument
[message] => line <line>:<position> no viable alternative at character '<first_cyrillic_symbol>'
```

**How can I pass them?**

Comment: How are you doing the query? Can you post the code you're using / method you're using to do it?

Comment: I'm using `cURL` utility in system shell (on Windows). Everything goes ok, as it should, without cyrillic symbols.

Comment: How are you and/or curl encoding the data to send to the server?

Comment: And also, does your query work (cyrillic and all) if you use the [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) to test with?

Comment: Thanks for `Workbench` link! In workbench picture is the same: only roman - works, with cyrillic - doesn't. Error message is the same too.

Comment: In `cURL` I'm using `--data` key, and then pass url-encoded parameters string.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Alfresco? And if not, what happens if you grab that + test with?

Comment: Version 5.0d (the latest).

Comment: Can you try the [December 2015 5.1 community preview](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Community_Edition_201512_EA_Release_Notes)? I believe it has a newer version of the Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS engine powering it's CMIS implementation, would be good to check if that's the issue or not

Comment: Unfortunately, I can use only 5.0d version.

Comment: Don't upgrade, just install it as a second copy to test with. That will let you work out if it's an issue with your slightly older version, or a general one

Comment: 5.0d is the latest stable version.

Comment: I'm very well aware of that! However, you need to work out if this is something that's fixed in a more recent version (in which case you need a backport), or an ongoing problem (needs reporting + workaround)